# Detecting IE 7 and 8 issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, version

The issue is simple: I need the version of IE. If it is 7 or earlier, I want to redirect. The code below works in all cases except when IE 8 accesses the page. It will work if IE 8 was not upgraded from 7. However, if it was upgraded, the value this returns is still 7, even though the About Internet Explorer help page shows the version as 8.0.etc. 
I am stuck. Any ideas?

```
var BrowserDetect = {
init: function () {
    this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
    this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
        || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
        || "an unknown version";
    this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
},
searchString: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataString = data[i].string;
        var dataProp = data[i].prop;
        this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
        if (dataString) {
            if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
        else if (dataProp)
            return data[i].identity;
    }
},
searchVersion: function (dataString) {
    var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
    if (index == -1) return;
    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
},
dataBrowser: [
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Chrome",
        identity: "Chrome"
    },
    { string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "OmniWeb",
        versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
        identity: "OmniWeb"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "Apple",
        identity: "Safari",
        versionSearch: "Version"
    },
    {
        prop: window.opera,
        identity: "Opera"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "iCab",
        identity: "iCab"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "KDE",
        identity: "Konqueror"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Firefox",
        identity: "Firefox"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.vendor,
        subString: "Camino",
        identity: "Camino"
    },
    {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Netscape",
        identity: "Netscape"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "MSIE",
        identity: "Explorer",
        versionSearch: "MSIE"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Gecko",
        identity: "Mozilla",
        versionSearch: "rv"
    },
    {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "Mozilla",
        identity: "Netscape",
        versionSearch: "Mozilla"
    }
],
dataOS: [
    {
        string: navigator.platform,
        subString: "Win",
        identity: "Windows"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.platform,
        subString: "Mac",
        identity: "Mac"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "iPhone",
        identity: "iPhone/iPod"
    },
    {
        string: navigator.platform,
        subString: "Linux",
        identity: "Linux"
    }
]

};
BrowserDetect.init();


var x = (BrowserDetect.browser);
var y = (BrowserDetect.version);
var z = (BrowserDetect.OS);
```

Y is still returning the version equaling 7, when IE is actually 8. However, this only happens on IE 8 when it has been upgraded from IE 7. It's driving me nuts. Why isn't it seeing the current browser equaling 8...

Comment: Have you looked into the conditional HTML comments? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Do you realize that IE8 can run as IE7? That is want you are probably seeing. Use F12 and look at what mode it is running in.

Comment: I run <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />  in the aspx, but the check is clearly, done in js. Which happens first?

Comment: @user1585004 You mean which happens first between the `meta` and the `script`? Definitely the `meta`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. So then, why are browsers that are running IE7 compat mode in IE8 behaving like ie 7? Since the meta is called.. Or is it possible it's something else entirely..

Comment: Thanks Ian, this was it. the meta definitely fixed the javascript. I had it outside of the <head> tag =\.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely *must* detect browsers, use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to target only IE:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://www.go-away-ie7.com/"
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: So if the browser is running compatability mode (I've since figured that one via the above) then will this resolve the issue? Will it determine IE8 is running in IE7 compat mode and move on, or will it still execute IE7 specific code on an IE8 browser?

Comment: @user1585004: No idea. I'm not running Windows ATM, but that shouldn't be hard for you to test.

Comment: This would've been so much easier from the get go... Thank you